# how to pass the object in html using thymeleaf

Tags: java

customer.html

```
<div class="table-responsive"> 
    <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" th:action="@{/customers}"          method="post" th:object="${user}">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Row</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Create Date</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                 <tr th:action="@{/customers}" method="post">
                     <td th:value="${info.firstName}">firstName</td>
                     <td th:value="${info.lastName}">lastName</td>
                     <td th:value="${info.createdate}">createdate</td>
                     <td th:value="${info.emailaddress}">emailaddress</td>
                 </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String customers(Model model) throws Exception {
    String firstName = "prasoon";
    String lastName = "gupta";
    String createdate = "2 july";
    String emailaddress = "prasoon.gupta@abc.com";
    List<Customers> info = scheduleService.getCustomer();
    model.addAttribute("info", info);
    return "pages/customers";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first question would be for what for you need define all those String if they´re not added into model?.

Here you have an example of how iterate a list in thymeleaf

```
         <table class="info table table-hover">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="customers : ${info}">

                        <td width="20%" th:text="${customers.id}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

About what you just ask me, I think you dont understand very good your own architecture. What do you expect receive on your info list?

To add an extra customers on your list hence in your model you have to do this, but I still think is a poor technique

```
        String firstName = "prasoon";
        String lastName = "gupta";
        String createdate = "2 july";
        String emailaddress = "prasoon.gupta@abc.com";
        Customers customers = new Customers();
        customers.setFirstName(firstName);
        customers.setLastName(lastName);
        customers.setCreatedate(createdate);
        customers.setEmailaddress(emailaddress);

        List<Customers> info = scheduleService.getCustomer();
        info.add(customers);
```

Comment: How to add them into model @paul

Comment: inside info i expect to receive first name last name , etc,,, and want tho show them inside table @paul

Comment: your welcome. Please add a vote and click the finish check if you consider the answer useful and your issue has been resolved